# Express app is requiring script tags in the wrong place

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs, pug

Basically, at `http://localhost:3000/` everything works fine, but when I go to `http://localhost:3000/post/23` I get the following error in the console.

`require.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Inspecting this in the network tab, I noticed that my client, when attempting to load require, loads it at `http://localhost:3000/post/require.js`, and then returns the html of my template instead. Note that `http://localhost:3000/require.js` works fine, but I can't get it to require at that url when I visit my `/post` url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>PodShuff</title><script data-main="requireconfig.js" src="require.js"></script><link href="normalize.css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><button id="theBuddon">New</button><h2>Title Here</h2><h4>Author Here</h4><p>Post Body Here</p></body></html>
```

Obviously part of the problem is that requirejs is being loaded at /post when I really want it to be required at the root url, but setting a base url doesn't seem to work. Also, why in the world would it require the html template instead of just saying "not found"? I've included my requireconfig and the relevant parts of my code below. How do I stop this console error and require the `require.js` the correct way?

The requireconfig
    'use strict';

```
require.config({
    paths: {
            faker: 'node_modules/faker/build/build/faker',
            text: './text',
            underscore: 'node_modules/underscore/underscore',
            jquery: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery',
            Backbone: 'node_modules/backbone/backbone',
            Post: '/public/scripts/post',
            PostCollection: '/public/scripts/post-collection',
            PostView: '/public/scripts/post-view',
            PostCollectionView: '/public/scripts/post-collection-view',
            main: '/public/scripts/main',
            dotenv: '/node_modules/dotenv/config',
            fakeData: 'public/scripts/fake-data',
        },
        baseUrl: "/"
});

require([
        'PostView',
        'Post',
        'PostCollection',
        'main',
]);
```

The Server

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/requirejs")));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/views")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/views/templates")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/scripts")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/stylesheets")));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.listen("3000", function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/post/:id", function(req, res){
    var rawPost = PostSchema.find({postId: req.params.id}, function(err, posts){
        var post = new Post(rawPost)
        res.render('single-post', {model: post});
    });
});
```

The jade template:

```
 //layout.jade
    doctype html
    html(lang="en")
        head
            title="PodShuff"
            script(data-main='requireconfig.js', src="require.js")
            link(href="normalize.css/normalize.css", rel="stylesheet")
            link(href="style.css", rel="stylesheet")
        body
            button(id="theBuddon")="New"
            block cont
```

Comment: `src="/require.js"`- also, you will wan to do the same with your other references (i.e. add the leading forward slash)

Comment: That's weird. It worked. But I tried that before and it didn't. Strange.

Comment: Hmm. Possibly something else was going on before. I feel like its too much of a gimme offering it is an answer. You might want to just delete the question if it has been resolved.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you! Although if you want to write a longer answer about why you would use the '/' in expressjs and what it means to relative and absolute paths, I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks - very kind. If I have some time this evening, I will expand on it a bit and see if I can think of any other related Jade gotchas. Some people really don't like Jade. Personally, I quite like it.

Comment: can anyone explain why "/" is needed in script src? it fixed one of my issue in multi page